# Salesforce Lightning Component Picklist Value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute

Hi have a requirement as follows:-

I want to make a Picklist value in the lightning component.
After using the lightning:Select still i am not able to get the values provided in the list.

Codes as below:

List Created:----

```
<aura:attribute name="NoOfHoursStudy" type="String[]" default=" ,Less Then 1 hrs,in between 1 to 4hrs,
                                                                   In between 4 to 8 hrs,More then 8hrs"/>
```

Lightning select and values:---

```
<div class="slds-size_3-of-8">  
    <lightning:Select label="How many hours do you study ?" name="hrsstudy" value="{!v.NoOfHoursStudy}"> 
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.NoOfHoursStudy}" var="hrs"/>
   <option value="{!hrs}" text="{!hrs}"/>
      </lightning:Select>   
</div>
```

Comment: Not able to get the Picklist Values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default value is incorrect. It must be contained in `[]` (support for lists without `[]` is deprecated) and have appropriate `'` characters.

```
<aura:attribute 
  name="NoOfHoursStudy" 
  type="String[]" 
  default="['','Less Then 1 hrs','in between 1 to 4hrs','In between 4 to 8 hrs','More then 8hrs']"/>
```

Also, your *options* attribute should be different than your selected value option, otherwise they'll get wiped out. Also, Lightning is case sensitive, so it should be `lightning:select` instead of `lightning:Select`.

```
<aura:attribute 
  name="NoOfHoursStudyOptions" 
  type="String[]" 
  default="['','Less Then 1 hrs','in between 1 to 4hrs','In between 4 to 8 hrs','More then 8hrs']"/>
<aura:attribute name="NoOfHoursStudy" type="String" />
<lightning:select 
  label="How many hours do you study ?" 
  name="hrsstudy" 
  value="{!v.NoOfHoursStudy}"> 
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.NoOfHoursStudyOptions}" var="hrs"/>
   <option value="{!hrs}" text="{!hrs}"/>
  </lightning:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting another answer if anyone facing similar issue. 
Problem is not in default value. You need to end your iteration(loop) after option not before.  Check this code :

```
> <aura:attribute name="NoOfHoursStudy" type="String[]" default=" ,Less
> Then 1 hrs,in between 1 to 4hrs,
>                                                                In between 4 to 8 hrs,More then 8hrs"/> <div class="slds-size_3-of-8">  
>     <lightning:Select label="How many hours do you study ?" name="hrsstudy" value="{!v.NoOfHoursStudy}"> 
>         <aura:iteration items="{!v.NoOfHoursStudy}" var="hrs">
>         <option value="{!hrs}" text="{!hrs}"/>
>         </aura:iteration>
>     </lightning:Select>    </div>
```